# Has anyone found a working Angular seed example for the latest 1.x, 2.x, or 4.x versions?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, maven

After over a half dozen attempts I have not.
I do get repeated debugging opportunities, but nothing seems to work.
TIA

Comment: There is an [Angular 2.x Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) that works fairly well (it requires some dependency changes to upgrade to 4.x, but that's easy enough)

Comment: WINNER!  Finally!  Thank you.